# Image Interpolation Help Needed

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to use my thermal sensor to change colors to an overlay that I have over the Android camera. The problem is that the data I get back is in a 16x4 array. How do I resize this 16x4 grid to a different resolution? Such as 32x8, 48x12...etc.

Edit:
For instance, I have this as my draw method:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++){
            // mapping 2D array to 1D array
            int index = x*GRID_WIDTH + y;
            tempVal = currentTemperatureValues.get(index);
            // 68x68 bitmap squares to display temperature data
            if(tempVal >= 40.0)
                bitmaps[x][y].eraseColor(Color.RED);
            else if(tempVal < 40.0 && tempVal > 35.0)
                bitmaps[x][y].eraseColor(Color.YELLOW);
            else
                bitmaps[x][y].eraseColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }

    combinedBitmap = mergeBitmaps();

    // combinedBitmap = fastblur(combinedBitmap,  45);
    paint.setAlpha(alphaValue);
    canvas.drawBitmap(combinedBitmap, xBitmap, yBitmap, paint);

    Log.i(TAG,"Done drawing");
}
```

The current implementation is to draw to a 16x4 overlay over my camera preview, but resolution is very low, and I'd like to improve it the best I can.

Comment: Please show some code that we can work with. It's impossible to know where to start to answer without more information from you.

Answer (score 0):

The `Bitmap` class in the Android API (that's what I'm assuming you're using) has a static method called `createScaledBitmap`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29

What this method does is that it accepts an already created `Bitmap`, you specify the final width and height dimensions as well as a `boolean` flag called `filter`.  Setting this to `false` does nearest neighbour interpolation while `true` does bilinear interpolation.

As an example, given that you have a 2D array of `Bitmap`s, you could resize one like so:

```
Bitmap resize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaps[x][y], 32, 8, true);
```

The first parameter is the `Bitmap` you want resized, the second parameter is the width, third parameter the height, and the last is the `filter` flag.  The output (of course) is stored in `resize` and is your resized / scaled image.  Currently, the Javadoc for this method (as you can see) provides no explanation for what `filter` does.  I had to look at the Android source to figure out what exactly it was doing, and also from experience as I have used the method before.

Generally, you set this to `false` if you are **shrinking** the image, while you set this to `true` if you are **upscaling** the image.  The reason why is because when you are interpolating an image from small to large, you are trying to create more information than what was initially available.  Doing this with nearest neighbour will introduce blocking artifacts, and so bilinear interpolation will help smooth this out.  Going from large to small has no noticeable artifacts using either method, and so you generally choose nearest neighbour as it's more computationally efficient.  There will obviously be blurring as you resize to a larger image.  The larger you go, the more blurriness you get, but that beats that blockiness you get with nearest neighbour.

For using just the Android API, this is the best and easiest solution you can get.  If you want to get into more sophisticated interpolation techniques (Cubic, Lanczos, etc...), unfortunately you will have to implement that yourself.  Try bilinear first and see what you get.

Comment: @ThomasSmythe: Do you require any further assistance?